# How to show the remaining disk space in the modeline?

Tags: mode-line

I might using the wrong search terms, thus I'm asking for this here:

How can I have modify my modeline to display my remaining disk space?

Currently I have to open a terminal in order to enter:

```
$ df -H --output=avail /dev/mapper/Arch-root | tail -n 1
```

results in `32G`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the function `free-disk-space` since Emacs 27. Modify your modeline to insert `(get-free-disk-space default-directory)`.

There are many ways to add information to the mode line. Do `C-h i g(elisp)mode line format` for all the gory details. And be prepared for some head scratching.

Here's an example if you want to add this information at the end of the mode line:

```el
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string (list " " '(:eval (get-free-disk-space default-directory))) t)
```

This works even on remote directories.

Comment: Thank you. *How* do I modify the modeline

Comment: Here's an example if you want to add this information at the end of the mode line: `(add-to-list 'global-mode-string (list " " '(:eval (get-free-disk-space default-directory))) t)`

Comment: Added the comments to the answer to make it self-contained.